# SignalException in at_exit on AWS ECS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, puma, amazon-ecs

We're running a Rails 5.1 app on ECS using a docker image based on the official `ruby:2.4.2` image.

On many deploys we receive this exception, from what I understand from the old process:

```
SignalException: SIGTERM - SignalException in at_exit

Backtrace:

[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:397 :in `block in setup_signals`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/single.rb:106 :in `join`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/single.rb:106 :in `run`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183 :in `run`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:77 :in `run`
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/puma-3.11.0/bin/puma:10 :in `<top (required)>`

/usr/local[GEM_ROOT]/bin/puma:21 :in `load`

19 require "bundler/setup"
20 
21 load Gem.bin_path("puma", "puma")

/usr/local[GEM_ROOT]/bin/puma:21 :in `<main>`
```

I found [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/pull/650) suggesting that setting `BUNDLE_DISABLE_EXEC_LOAD` to `true` would resolve the issue, but it did not.

Also, note the `in at_exit` part. Is it possible that our shutdown takes too long so ECS sends another `SIGTERM` before the process terminated properly?

---

The command is

```
"command": [
    "bin/ecs",
    "webserver"
  ]
```

and `bin/ecs` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

COMMANDS = {
  "webserver" => "puma -C config/puma.rb",
  "sidekiq" => "sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml"
}

system("bundle", "exec", "rake", "db:abort_if_pending_migrations")

exit $?.exitstatus unless $?.success?

command = COMMANDS[ARGV.first].split(" ")
exec(*command)
```

We do this to avoid running a shell somewhere because that swallows signals. We also set a high stop timeout to make sure long-running sidekiq tasks don't get killed:

```
ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT=1h
```

The container exits quite fast, so the timeout is not the problem. If it would be killed, it also couldn't report about it, could it?

Comment: Could you share your command for running the container?

Comment: @Kkulikovskis shared

Comment: So this happens to be part of the new deployment and the container exits?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm pretty sure it's coming from the container that's supposed to terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Honeybadger is reporting the signal exception, but should ignore it. And it will with the next release after 3.3.0 (not yet released) https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-ruby/pull/269